# Why is the html "selected" attribute not working here?

Tags: html, selectedindex

The selected option is not working for the following code:

```
<form>
    <select name="test" multiple>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C" selected>C</option>
    </select>
</form
```

I've looked at the other posts here on this topic and none of the answers are working for me. I'm using chrome and a cherrypy framework. When I run it in a new, separate html file using pycharm on my computer it works fine, but if I try using it on my workplace server nothing gets selected. Please let me know if I should provide other relevant data. Thanks.

Comment: "When I run it in a new, separate html file using pycharm on my computer it works fine" — Then the problem isn't with the code you provided. It is something to do with your "workplace server"

Comment: Yeah that would make sense, just wondering if there's some idea of where I could look to fix the problem.